# Load tooltip text dynamically

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, quasar

Is it possible to load the q-tooltip text dynamically?

What property to use?

In my example,  what is the correct property to use instead of **:value** (*this property does not exist in the q-tooltip and is for demonstration only*)?

```
<q-item-section avatar>
     <q-icon :name="typeIcon(item.type_item)" />
     <q-tooltip :value="tooltipIcon(item.type_item)" transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale" content-class="bg-primary"  />
</q-item-section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use your method inside of the `q-tooltip` tags to set text. I don't see any problem with that:

```html
<q-tooltip>
   {{ tooltipIcon(item.type_item) }}
</q-tooltip>
```

Comment: Thanks Serg. Works great.